# php notification when a new entry with sound

Tags: javascript, php, html

i want make a real time notification with jquery and play sound first play when a new entry added , but my script the audio play repeated

front end :

```
<script>
    setInterval(
    function()
    {
    $('#orderjum').load('refresh/jumlahorder.php');}, 1000);

    </script>
```

backend :

```
<?
require("../../include/koneksi.php");
$sql = "Select * FROM pemesanan";
$result = mysqli_query($konek,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($konek));
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "<h3>$num_rows</h3>
<p>Total Orders</p> <audio controls autoplay hidden='true'>
<source src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/horse.ogg' type='audio/ogg'>
</audio>";exit;
?>
```

Comment: you are not doing anything with result.you keep refreshing and sound play continuously

Answer (score 6):

U should create a script (in [PHP](https://secure.php.net/)) so that u can have a option to check with JS AJAX if anything changed. The PHP file (say name of the file is - **backend_file.php**) will just return **true** if anything updated and false if no new event happened.

So, in that case the JS code for that would be like this-

```js
setTimeout("checkUpdate()",1000); //poll every second


function checkUpdate()
{
    $.post("backend_file.php", function(data, status)
    {
       if (data.toString()=="true")
       {
          playSound();
       }
    });
}

function playSound()
{
    var audio = new Audio('http://www.rangde.org/static/bell-ring-01.mp3');
    audio.play();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script>
setInterval(
function()
{
$('#orderjum').load('refresh/jumlahorder.php');}, 1000);
setTimeout("checkUpdate()",1000); //poll every second


function checkUpdate()
{
    $.post("refresh/jumlahorder.php", function(data, status)
    {
       if (data.toString()=="true")
       {
          playSound();
       }
    });
}

function playSound()
{
    var audio = new Audio('http://www.rangde.org/static/bell-ring-01.mp3');
    audio.play();
}

i can't play bro ??

Comment: U should place a mp3 or audio file in the source bro. So place a valid mp3 file in place of "http://www.rangde.org/static/bell-ring-01.mp3" .

Comment: Works for me, please ck if there is any other JS error in your code

Comment: ask , your script place in my frontend php or backend php ??